# Assembly find max of two value

Tags: assembly, fasm

I'm trying to find maximum between two values

```
_FindMax:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, dword [ebp+12]  ; get fist argument
    mov ebx, dword [ebp+8]   ; get second argument


    cmp eax, ebx
    jl LESS       ; if eax less to LESS

    LESS:
    mov eax, ebx ; ebx is greate and return it

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp

    ret
```

but problem is that LESS: label is executing always. for example if parameters are  equal then LESS: label is executing. Why??

Comment: if the branch is not taken, the code is automatically running into LESS. you have to jump OVER the code you want to skip

Comment: What did you expect it to execute, when "not less" is true (I mean when `jl` is not jumping)? BTW, you can also use conditional `cmovCC`, in this case `cmovl eax,ebx` would resolve it without branching.

Comment: Thanks all of you . Problem solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A really efficient way to achieve this would be (assuming that you have at least a P6 family processor):

```
_FindMax:
    mov eax, dword [esp+8]       /* get first argument */
    mov ebx, dword [esp+4]       /* get second argument */
    cmp eax, ebx                 /* compare EAX to EBX */
    cmovl eax, ebx               /* MOV EBX to EAX if EBX > EAX */
    ret
```

This code omits the stack frame (EBP) and uses an inline `MOV` operation to do the comparison. Nevertheless, the return value is still in `EAX`.

Comment: Can you comment on why this is efficient? Is it because it avoids the jump?

Comment: Because it has (close to) minimum instructions, avoids the stack frame  and has no jumps. A version with one instruction less is possible: `mov eax, dword [esp+8] -- cmp eax, dword [esp+4] -- cmovl eax, dword [esp+4] -- ret`. But it's probably not faster than the one above - however, it saves one register.

Answer (score 2):

the code in LESS is always executed, regardless if the branch is taken, or not. You need to skip the code you don't want to execute:

```
_FindMax:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, dword [ebp+12]  ; get fist argument
    mov ebx, dword [ebp+8]   ; get second argument


    ; invert the condition, and jump over the code to skip
    cmp eax, ebx
    jge SKIP       ; jmp and return, if aex is the larger one

    mov eax, ebx   ; ax is NOT larger, so return ebx

    SKIP:
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp

    ret
```